# Find and delete text in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to programming .bat files.  I need to create a batch file that deletes all "" in a txt file.  For example, I would want the following:

**"","","","01","","Dan",**

to look like this:

**,,,"01",,"Dan",**

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this:- type file.txt | findstr /v ""

Comment: It is easier to do it in Powershell with `set-content`, Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do set a=%%i&set a=!a:""=! &echo !a!>>new.txt
```

this will make a new file "new.txt" with the ""s removed. to over write the old file add this:
 `del a.txt&ren new.txt a.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use find and replace

Find "" and replace it with nothing (keeping 'replace with' box empty)

Comment: In a batch file is no box, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Put `repl.bat` in the same folder as the `batch file` and `text file`, or you can type this at a cmd prompt in the folder with repl and the text file.

```
@echo off
type "file.txt" |repl.bat "\x22\x22" "" >"newfile.txt"
```